# Configure gem installation directory to match user installation directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm familiar with the node/npm way, and trying to get set up using ruby/gem/bundler as well.

The output from `gem env` includes these lines:

```
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.1 (2018-03-29 patchlevel 57) [x86_64-darwin17]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/local/lib/ruby2.5/gems/2.5.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/ssterling3/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
```

(I don't get why gems for ruby 2.5.1 would be installed in dir named 2.5.0, but that's not what this question is about.)

**I don't want `gem` to ever touch anything outside of `$HOME`, and I want to do so in a way that I'll never have to edit even when I upgrade ruby or move the content of `$HOME` to a different computer where I have a different username.**

(Sure, I'll have to reinstall all the gems or something, that's also not what this question is about.)

**I think the right way to do it is to override the default `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` and set it to always match the default `USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY`.**

**How can I do that?**

I know I can override the `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` by setting `$GEM_HOME`, but I don't know how to get gem to output the `USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` in a way I won't have to parse before setting `$GEM_HOME`.  I can get the `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` from `gem env gemdir`, but `gem env --user-install gemdir` says `Invalid option`.

(Why one value has three dissimilar names and a closely related value only has the least usable analogous name are both also not what this question is about.)

I know I can configure some things in `$HOME/.gemrc`, but the documentation and examples I found didn't make it clear to me how to manipulate the `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY`.  It sounded like I might be able to do it by adding the line `gem: --user-install`, but maybe it has to be at least three lines for `install`, `uninstall`, and `update`, but adding the line with `gem:` doesn't change the output of `gem env` so maybe none of those will really do what I want.

Comment: Your question is hard to follow. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but you should probably look at using a version manager I suggest http://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: Well, I had a choice between just asking the small form of the question and getting beaten over the head with comments about things I already know or tried and didn't mention, or being verbose and sharing what I know and tried and having some people lose track of the question.  But I'll try to highlight the core of the question a bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting this atrocity in my init scripts:

```
if [ ! -z "`which gem`" ]; then
        GEM_HOME=`prefix="  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: "; line=\`gem env | grep "^$prefix"\`; suffix=${line#$prefix}; echo $suffix`
fi;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update environment variables. For my output:

```
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.1 (2018-03-29 patchlevel 57) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ivan/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/ivan/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1
     - /home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global
```

my file is located here:

`home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/environment`

Note the `environment` file is into `GEM PATHS` first path.

**Important**: I should reload variables by:

`source home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/environment`

or faster in most of shells:

`. home/ivan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/environment`

Comment: What goes in that environment file? Where does the file go if I'm not using rvm? Is there a command that outputs the `GEM PATHS` for use in a script?  If that `environment` file is just a sourceable shell script, why set things there rather than in my shell init scripts? Which environment variables should be set?  Where are they documented? I already know about `$GEM_HOME`, and I set it in my answer, I'm not sure what you're saying here that's actually new. Your output shows an `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` within `$HOME`, due to rvm, but how does that relate to your `USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY`?